# Selenium C# - Doesn't find certains elements when using headless Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm running my **Chrome driver** with the `headless` option to make my life a lot easier, but on some sites, my `CssSelector` doesn't find a certain element, the strange thing is that when I run my code without the option, the `CssSelector` returns me the list that I'm looking for, does this have something to do with the `headless` argument I'm using?

Here is a code example with the problem:

```cs
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using System;
    
    namespace rpa.testeHeadless
    {
        class Program
        {
            static ChromeDriver ReturnDriver()
            {
                var args = new ChromeOptions();
    
                args.AddArguments("headless");
                args.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
                args.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
                args.AddArguments("log-level=3");
    
                return new ChromeDriver(args);
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var driver = ReturnDriver();
    
                driver.Url = "https://www.boticario.com.br/api/htmls/showcase?uri=/perfumaria&size=36&pagina=1";
    
                var itens = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class='showcase-item   js-event-product-click ']"));
    
                Console.WriteLine("\nItens found: " + itens.Count);
    
            }
        }
    }
```